Can I use multiple complex sorts as tie breakers in Elasticsearch without using scripts?
I'm trying to perform multiple sorts in Elasticsearch, where each sort acts as a tie breaker for the previous one. However, I want to avoid using scripts (like Painless) for custom sorting logic.
For example, I want products that are not active and have a price < 10 to appear at the end of the list, with the inner order among those products determined by the score field.
The query below does that, but using script.
I've tried using boosting, but I don't have any prior knowledge about the scores, so I can't determine an efficient boosting factor in advance.
any ides?
thanks
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "score"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 4,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "active", 
      "score",
      "price"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "return doc['active'].value == false || doc['price'].value < 10 ? 1: 0",
          "params": {}
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ]
}


Answer #1. Inverted Condition & dis_max
Yes, you can use complex sorting
Sample documents
PUT /complex_sorting/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"active":false,"price":9}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"active":false,"price":8}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"active":true,"price":100}

Query with complex sorting. I use the dis_max query to boost active products AND with price greater than 10
GET /complex_sorting/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits._score
{
    "query": {
        "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "active": {
                                        "value": "true"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "price": {
                                        "gt": 10
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_score" : 3.9616582,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : true,
                    "price" : 100
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : false,
                    "price" : 9
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : false,
                    "price" : 8
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Adjust the boost parameter as you need

Answer #2. The boosting query
There is another way to solve your issue without a script. You could use the boosting query and place your script conditions into the negative section of the query
Sample documents
PUT /negative_boosting/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"active":false,"score":1,"price":9}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"active":false,"score":2,"price":10}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"active":true,"score":3,"price":9}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"active":true,"score":4,"price":10}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"active":true,"score":5,"price":20}

boosting query
GET /negative_boosting/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "boosting": {
            "positive": {
                "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "field_value_factor": {
                                "field": "score"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "negative": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "active": {
                                    "value": "false"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "price": {
                                    "lt": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "negative_boost": 0.1
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "negative_boosting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "5",
                "_score" : 5.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : true,
                    "score" : 5,
                    "price" : 20
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "negative_boosting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "4",
                "_score" : 4.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : true,
                    "score" : 4,
                    "price" : 10
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "negative_boosting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 0.3,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : true,
                    "score" : 3,
                    "price" : 9
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "negative_boosting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.2,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : false,
                    "score" : 2,
                    "price" : 10
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "negative_boosting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.1,
                "_source" : {
                    "active" : false,
                    "score" : 1,
                    "price" : 9
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

